# Sql profiler For an specfic User of an web application

Tags: sql-server

I am using a web Application i get an user defined error in the application i want to use sql profiler for the specific user for that application.Please can some one help.

Answer (score 1):

Tools->SQL Server Profiler-->connect->Trace Properties[Events Selection]->Column Filters->Login Name[Like]='poo' & ApplicationName[Like]='%App%'

```
Run
```